# Determine if arithmetic expression is in language described by grammar

Tags: grammar

We have the following grammar for arithmetic questions:

E → E + T  |  E – T | T

T → T * F  |  T / F | F

F → ( E )  |  a | b

I'm trying to determine whether (a+b)(a-b) is in the language described by the grammar.

I was able to see that (a+b)*(a-b) is in the language so does that mean that (a+b)(a-b) is in the language? The lack of an asterisk is throwing me off. The preceding exercises have asterisks for multiplication.

Comment: Why the downvote? I was asking about how explicit the grammar of a language must be. I was not asking for someone to do the entire problem--I have already done so.

Comment: What is the point of a formal language description if it is not, in fact, formal? Yes, a grammar means exactly what it says, nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

> so does that mean that (a+b)(a-b) is in the language?

No

Because. You would be able to produce `(a+b)(a-b)` from four `non-terminals`  combination ie `TT`, `TF`, `FT`, `FF` and these four combinations can not be produced from given grammar.